# What is the equivalent resistance between A and B?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

I was solving this problem:

[image]

As it appears, this is a collection of resistors put on the sides of trapezoidal pyramid. I have solved this problem and my answer is \$ \frac{12R}{35}\Omega\$, but the answer in the book is \$ \frac{2R}{5} \Omega\$, so I am wondering what went wrong in my calculation?

My attempt to solve this:-

[image: Between A and B I have figured the equivalent resistance to be R/2 so is between E and C]

Comment: Can you show the steps you take?

Comment: Are all the resistors identical? Maybe you should identify them with reference names. Maybe redraw using the tools provided.

Comment: Yes all are equivalent

Comment: @PMF, I have solved using the symmetry plan that passes through mid AB, mid AC, and the point D.

Comment: @PMF the symmetry plan is used after figuring the resistance between AB which is R/2 and the the resistance between EC which is also R/2.

Comment: @Jack no that doesn't work. You cannot immediately reduce the resistance between any two nodes to R/2.  You start by splitting at D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell you your error, but I solved it like this:[image]

Because of symmetry, you can redraw node D into D and D' which are both at potential V/2 so no current flows between them. Having split D into two separate nodes, you can take the parallel equivalent of 2R and 1R, which is 2R/3. This redraws as the top figure.

Then you redraw again and see that that 2R/3 resistor has no current anyway, because voltages at either end are also the same, V/2 again. So you remove it, and after that it is just a simple parallel resistance calculation, which comes out at 2R/5.

In other words : nodes C, D and E all turn out to be at V/2, so you can redraw as a simple parallel circuit.

Comment: can you please look at my attempt. I have attached a picture in the question.

Comment: there seems to be an issue with your first step - you have some resistors reduced to R/2 there, which is not possible if you look carefully at the initial circuit. Nowhere there are there two resistors directly in parallel.

Comment: Isn't the resistance from A to B not A to C. I am taking about that one on the wire with a hook

Comment: I don't really follow what you are saying. I suggest you look carefully at my answer and/or that of Andy aka, and try to follow the logic, especially the first step.

Comment: What I wanted to say is, is there a resistor connected between the point A and the point C. I see two resistors from the point A the point B, and one from A to D, and another from A to E. I don't see a resistor connected between A and C.

Comment: yes there is. In fact every possible pair of points has exactly one resistor between them, initially.

Answer (score 1):

Due to symmetry and all resistors being equal there are some immediate simplifications to be made: -

[image]

Node D can be reduced because you know there can be no current in the former connection I removed. This then reduces the circuit by two resistors to this: -

[image]

Then, the three resistors at the top can be reduced to one resistor: -

[image]

Can you take it from here? Hint: note that the voltage at E and C has to be identical.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but why the voltage at E=the voltage at C?

Comment: @Jack it's down to mental trial and error; I can see symmetry between E and C so, in my mind, I removed that upper horizontal resistor to test my thoughts. Clearly, after removing that resistor both E and C are each fed by two remaining resistors of equal value from points A and B. That means they have the same voltage and therefore, there can be no current through through the resistor I removed hence, it can be permanently removed (either opened or shorted).